# Merge overlapping/neighboring polygons - GeoPandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I am reading a [shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8i7rnnd0p3ly58/Comunas.zip?dl=0) and I have extracted a specific row from it that is a `Multipolygon`. I can extract all the polygons in it with `.explode()` which works great and I get 130+ polygons.

How can I merge the ones that are next to each other?

I know the 130+ resulting polygons represent two islands, and I want to get each as a polygon. I have looked up how to do it but haven't been able to find anything and this is my first project ever using `geopandas` and `shapely`.

```
gdf=gpd.read_file("comunas.shp").to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
Rapa_Nui=gdf.loc[gdf["Comuna"]=="Isla de Pascua"]
all_Rapa_Nui=Rapa_Nui.explode()
```

Comment: The linked shapefile is not readable for me (note that a shapefile always comes as multiple files, you might need to zip them to share)

Comment: Thanks! I changed the link to contain the zip

Answer (score 4):

You can first union all polygons with `unary_union`:

```
single_multi_polygon = all_Rapa_Nui.unary_union
```

This should now be a single MultiPolygon consisting of two polygons for the two islands. And then you can get the polygon parts of this MultiPolygon:

```
polygons = single_multi_polygon.geoms
```

Comment: That still returns the 167 polygons.

Comment: I checked the data, and apart from one big island, there seem to be many small islands, so it seems logical that it still returns many polygons.

Comment: Oh then it's my bad.`.explode()` and your answer lead to the same amount of polygons so I just assumed it wasn't working. I guess I can't see all those tiny polygons on the plots I have been making so I just thought the big pieces of land were a mix of a lot of polygons .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came across this question looking for a way of merging 'touching' polygons that don't overlap but share parts of an edge:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75224634/7930235

```
gdf.geometry.buffer(0.1).unary_union.buffer(-0.1)
```